# How to circulate hot air from the upstairs?

Tags: air-conditioning, ceiling-fan, stairs

We have a heat pump in the bedroom, which is right next to the top stairs but the cool air doesn't circulate much outside the room. All the hot, humid air seems to 'sit' at the top of the steps so I was thinking of replacing the light with a ceiling fan at the top of the steps to help move/pull the air from the bedroom into the hallway?

Comment: Hot air rises and cool air drops.  It seems you have only one place for the two air types to move though so it acts like a blockage.  A fan/s might help but should have two passes/ducts so the air can circulate.

Comment: When you say, "We have a heat pump in the bedroom," do you mean you have a mini-split?  How is the rest of the living space HVAC'ed?

Answer (score 1):

This is more brainstorming than answer, I'm afraid, but you might want to try one of these and see if it helps.

For what it's worth: I have a similar problem during winter -- minisplits on both levels, want to put less energy into upper floor HVAC during the day, but heat rises so I get a draft up the open stairwell.

I have experimented with setting up my own "return" duct using 25' of dryer-exhaust flexible ducting and an inline duct fan. Results have been inconclusive, and I think closing doors on the upstairs rooms to isolate the stairwell and hall from outside may actually be more effective.

Putting a door at the top of the stairwell is tempting but my building's design would make that difficult. I might be able to get away with a curtain of some sort but haven't come up with anything I like yet.

(Didn't have this problem when heating with the radiators because the builders out one large radiator at the base of the stairs, turning it into its own convection cell, avd because radiators heat from floor level. Minisplit throwing heat from ceiling level, at fewer points, seems to set me up for this draft. It's one of the few things that disappoints me about the minisplit, and I think it's solvable but haven't found the best answer yet.)